# Auto case number based on a specific record type?

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, record-type, auto-number

We have around 10 case record types. We have one specific record type for our service cases. We want the cases to be assigned an auto case number whenever a new case is created. We do have a auto number field but it's updating for every case that is created.

Auto case number shouldn't be assigned when cases are created in other record types. For ex: If there are 8 cases under this record type, I want the 9th case to to have SR-009 as the custom case number instead of SR-020, assuming other record type cases are created. How do I achieve it?

Comment: You cannot skip auto number generation on a field utilized for that purpose. You will need to utilize another field here. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried using process builder with flow as a quick action. That didn't really worked out as expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: You will end up creating another field with some level of customization thus introducing a bit of maintenance overhead just to achieve this. I will rather recommend not to go any custom route for this purpose.

Comment: Hello Jayant, What is the best possible approach to achieve the requirement?

Comment: You would write a trigger. I'll link it for you.